# Is Every transcendental entire function $f(z) = C + \exp a + \exp b + \exp c $?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, exponential-sum

Let $z$ be a complex number and let $f(z)$ be any transcendental entire function.

Is it true that $f(z) = C +  \exp a + \exp b + \exp c $ where $ a,b,c $ are entire functions of $z$ and $C$ is a constant ?

If so, for a given $f$ in Taylor form is there an easy way to compute $a,b,c,C$ ?

Note that $C$ is not neccessarily equal to $f(0)$.

If the conjecture is true is there a unique solution for every $f(z)$ ?

Comment: Strange but the question marks seem to move around and end Up at wrong places when rotating my phone. The rest is fine.

Comment: @gerry transcendental !!

Comment: OK, $e^z+z$, then.

Comment: IMPORTANT I added the constant C in the OP thus the conjecture is slightly weakened.

Comment: What motivates this conjecture? Why 3 functions?

Comment: It's certainly not unique, e.g., $e^z=e^z+e^t+e^{t+\pi i}$ for any $t$.

Comment: Gerry Myerson , you are correct. But Maybe unique after adding Some conditions such as not being of the form X + exp Y + exp Z ? X constant , Y and Z entire.

Comment: @ Lhf because it fails to be true that f = exp A + exp B. This is easy to prove, set A(z) = B(z) - pi i. You can finish the proof I assume.

Comment: What's a transcendental function ?